# Remove a sub-site from SharePoint on a certain date using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Hi I am trying to run a PowerShell command that will delete my survey sub-site on January 1st. I have the command to delete the sub-site, but I am unsure how to set it to remove the sub-site on the date.

Any Help would be appreciated

```
Remove-SPWeb http://Sharepoint/Survey.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a Powershell script as an action on a scheduled task in Windows Task Scheduler- See here: [Use task scheduler to run Powershell Script](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/08/11/weekend-scripter-use-the-windows-task-scheduler-to-run-a-windows-powershell-script/)

Before you do this, and depending on your requirements, you might want to consider retention policies. Specifically site closure and deletion policies- See here: [How to set site closure and deletion policies](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-set-site-closure-and-deletion-policies-in-sharepoint-online/)

And here is further information on retention policies to help you understand if this is applicable to you. [Overview of retention policies](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Overview-of-retention-policies-5e377752-700d-4870-9b6d-12bfc12d2423)